# Who's credentials are used for the Authorisation Code Grant?

Tags: docusignapi

I implemented Authorisation Code Grant like the example code provided using passport and it is working fine.

One thing that is confusing me is that when obtaining a new token, passport required authentication.

Are these supposed to be the credentials of our admin account? or, once we go live, is it the credentials of our user who is trying to sign a document (using embedded signing).

Thanks!

Comment: please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

> our user who is trying to sign a document (using embedded signing)

note that signers do not need a DocuSign account. They can have one, but they don't need one.

If you want to use embedded signing for a signer who does not have a DocuSign account, use a system account (and JWT Grant) to obtain the Signing Ceremony URL. (A system account can also be used to create the envelope, if necessary.)

### Added

A "system account" is a user account in your DocuSign account that represents a generic, system, sender. For example, create a user account "Sales department." Then use JWT Grant (on your backend web server) to impersonate the Sales department user. The result is an access token that your application can use to create envelopes and then have them signed by your website visitors.

The "Sales department" user will be created and controlled by your system administrator. But there is no need for the system administrator to login every morning -- once the system administrator gives `consent` for the application to impersonate the Sales department user, your application can create new access tokens as needed that impersonate the Sales Department user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When you say system account, then practically speaking the system admin will have to sign in once a day to get the ball rolling?

Answer (score 0):

The latter. When using Auth Code Grant, every user of your application will have to log into DocuSign and their credentials will be used.

Read more over here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

Comment: anytime. Feel free to ask me more questions if you need help